# Manual install or Docker containers for setting up software on RaspPi?

Tags: docker

I’m planning my first RaspPi project, and it has a few software components.

I was intending to install and set up each piece of software manually.

While planning the project, I came across a script that more or less sets up the software I need by configuring and spinning up several Docker containers.

What factors should I consider when deciding between these two approaches?

I’m pretty sure the Docker containers will save me an hour or two of initial set up (though I should note that my project does not require too many dependencies, and that set up could be scripted if I ever need to duplicate or rebuild the project again).

But I’m wondering about maintainability, troubleshooting, performance, etc. in the long term.

Would welcome some advice from others who have experience running software within Docker containers on RaspPi.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that your questions more likely align with a Docker question rather than a Raspberry Pi question. Docker can be [easily installed on a Raspberry Pi](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/docker-on-raspberry-pi) using a simple bash script. As for performance, [this question has been answered already on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26149994/5871303). This also depends on which Raspberry Pi you are running. A Raspberry Pi 4 with 8GB of RAM will certainly perform differently than a Raspberry Pi 3a+ with only 512mb of RAM. On the first option, you can most likely get away with running various containers so long as the architecture is supported, but for the 3a+, it may struggle due to its limited resources.

Docker also provides a great article for [Getting Started with Docker on Arm for Linux](https://www.docker.com/blog/getting-started-with-docker-for-arm-on-linux/) that you could check out.